# running perl from python without hardcoding location

Tags: python

I have a python script which runs Perl script

```
perl = "C:\\perl64\\bin\\perl.exe"
perl_script = "C:\\Users\\gdarmon\\test.pl"
pl_script = subprocess.Popen([perl, perl_script,"test.bin", "test.vhx", "--width=128"], stdout=sys.stdout)
```

I do not want to hardcode the location of perl installation.
how can I find it? windows and linux 
python 3.8

Comment: If you add it to your system's path variable, you could just call `perl` instead of explicitly specifying its location. Have you tried that?

Comment: @RandomDavis yes I thought maybe there is a better way for finding out from inside the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Python 3.8 you may consider using [`shutil.which`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) to resolve `perl` for the first argument for `Popen`, for example:

```
>>> which('perl')
'/usr/bin/perl'
```

Should also work under Windows

```
>>> which('perl')
'C:\\perl\\bin\\perl.EXE'
```

This assumes that the relevant path is registered at the `PATH` environment variable (in my case under Windows, `PATH` should contain a reference to `C:\perl\bin`).  If that isn't found, the result will be `None`, which your application may handle as an error (e.g. inform the user that it couldn't find `perl`).

Answer (score 2):

This would normally be resolved by placing `perl` in your PATH.

```
>type a.pl
print "Hi!\n";

>python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.Popen([ 'perl', 'a.pl' ]).wait()"
Hi!
```

If you have an association for `.pl` files, and if you involve the shell, you can execute the .pl file directly.

```
>python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.Popen([ 'a.pl' ], shell=True).wait()"
Hi!
```